# Locked out of MySQL server - CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos

I have a server running CentOS and I installed myphp, phpmyadmin, mysql, mysql-server and it asks me for a password when trying to run the mysql safe install. I have not set a password and it says if you have not set one, then press enter, but this doesn't not work. Also I can't stop mysql and reinstall because that gives me the error:

> mysql access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

I've looked about a few places online and I cant find any fixes.

Comment: Are you connecting using the mysql command line client? If so, have you tried doing so without the -p option?

Comment: im just doing it in ssh on my centos server. Its for a school projects (i need to use php scripts to send info from a web form to my sql database) so im not 100% sure if im doing everything right.

Comment: Please show the command you're entering in the ssh terminal

Comment: 'mysql_secure_installation' im trying to do this but it asks for a password and doesnt accept anything i give it (i havent set a password, and i tried just pressing enter) so ive tried 'mysql -u root' and this says "access denied for root@localhost"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's possible, shut down the mysql daemon (`service mysql stop`). You can start it in safe mode to skip authorization with `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`. Then you can connect to it as root without password and reset the password.

Comment: `mysqld` is most likely in `/usr/sbin/mysqld`.

Comment: not there, although i did find a mysqld script in etc/initd./mysqld

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I did was `service mysql stop` and then `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` whilst I was in the root directory. What I did not realise was that when I do this, I am now in the SQL command line. This was my first time using mysql and so when the `[root@blahblah]` wasn't showing in the left side, I thought that the process has crashed but that was not true. Once I realised that I was actually in the SQL command line I was able to change my password.